# Python Queue future events

Tags: python, events, sleep, telethon

I am programming a Telegram bot in python, using the telethon framework. It all works fine, but I came to one thing which is weird. There are some messages I am sending to people including a sleep, meaning for example, that I want to sent something in two hours (sleep (7200)) or in one day (sleep(86400). As of the fact that every messages runs in it‘s own thread, this is not difficult. But it is bad style and also, all messages disappear when I restart the bot after programming something new.
Now I am thinking about a serious data structure to queue all the events which are going to run in the future. I want to have a structure which I can save if leaving the application (like writing into a txt file), which I could do with normal heaps, queues, stacks etc.
But my problem is to run the events as well.

Is there a good data structure, something good to import in python which proofs automatically if the timestamp of the first element (might be a min-heap having the element with the next time in it) is due, such that I can run it?

Comment: are you using any database?

Comment: Not yet. But I am also accepting interesting ideas including a SQL database.

Comment: At the moment, every message I am sending is an own thread which I set to sleep if I don’t want to sent it directly. The thread thing is part of the framework I am using. But I could instead send the message into some sort of database and close the thread afterwards.

Comment: You can try  http://www.celeryproject.org/  which support scheduling tasks (persistent), using redis/rabbitmq